# Nested json object with Jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I want:

```
{ 
    status: 200, 
    response: 
    { 
        user: { id: 1, name: 'Bob', city: 'New York' } 
    } 
}
```

What I have tried:

```
json.status 200
json.user json.(@user, :id, :name, :city)
```

But it does not give the desired results:

```
{
    "status" : "200"
    "response" : "{"status":200,"id":1, name: "bob", city: "New York","user":["id","name","city"]}"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
json.status 200
json.response do
  json.user @user.as_json(only: [:id, :name, :city])
end
```

Comment: No this does not do what I asked for in the question.  Your solution nests response inside of response like this: {
    "status" : "200"
    "response" : "{"status":200, "response": {"id":1, name: "bob", city: "New York","user":["id","name","city"]}}"
}. You see the difference from what I asked?

Comment: Just doing this worked: json.user @user.as_json(only: [:id, :name, :city])